# Dynamic component publish issue in tridion 2013

Tags: 2013, content-delivery, broker, database, dynamic-publishing

We are facing an issue while publishing  dynamic component from Tridion
CME.

Error Description :

> Caused by:  org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException:
>   Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not
>   establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets
>   Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server returned an incomplete
>   response. The connection has been closed.
>   ClientConnectionId:4dbd839f-e7bc-4914-86ff-e13c9d9424e9".
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:280)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
>           ... 37 common frames omitted Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not
>   establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets
>   Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server returned an incomplete
>   response. The connection has been closed.
>   ClientConnectionId:4dbd839f-e7bc-4914-86ff-e13c9d9424e9".
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1667)
>   ~[sqljdbc-4.0.jar:na]
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1668)
>   ~[sqljdbc-4.0.jar:na]
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1323)
>   ~[sqljdbc-4.0.jar:na]
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:991)
>   ~[sqljdbc-4.0.jar:na]
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
>   ~[sqljdbc-4.0.jar:na]
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
>   ~[sqljdbc-4.0.jar:na]
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(SimpleDriverDataSource.java:140)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:149)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
>           ... 38 common frames omitted Caused by: java.io.IOException: SQL Server returned an incomplete response. The connection has been
>   closed. ClientConnectionId:4dbd839f-e7bc-4914-86ff-e13c9d9424e9
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.ensureSSLPayload(IOBuffer.java:651)
>   ~[sqljdbc-4.0.jar:na]
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:708)
>   ~[sqljdbc-4.0.jar:na]
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:700)
>   ~[sqljdbc-4.0.jar:na]
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:895)
>   ~[sqljdbc-4.0.jar:na]
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:883)
>   ~[sqljdbc-4.0.jar:na]
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:422)
>   ~[na:1.6]
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:460)
>   ~[na:1.6]
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:863)
>   ~[na:1.6]
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
>   ~[na:1.6]
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1215)
>   ~[na:1.6]
>           at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)
>   ~[na:1.6]
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1618)
>   ~[sqljdbc-4.0.jar:na]
>           ... 47 common frames omitted 2016-07-21 09:59:21,351 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Final attempt in Phase: Deployment Processing
>   Phase failed for transaction: tcm:0-758380-66560 2016-07-21
>   09:59:21,351 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Original stack trace for
>   transaction: tcm:0-758380-66560
>   com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException:
>   com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Problem with searchIdent
>   fiks_bedrift. Returned ERROR
>           at com.tridion.deployer.extensions.base.ActionManager.executeActions(ActionManager.java:455)
>   ~[sdl_custom_deployer-2013SP1-1.0.jar:na]
>           at com.tridion.deployer.extensions.base.ActionManager.executePostActions(ActionManager.java:545)
>   ~[sdl_custom_deployer-2013SP1-1.0.jar:na]
>           at com.tridion.deployer.extensions.deploy.modules.PageDeploy.processPage(PageDeploy.java:69)
>   ~[sdl_custom_deployer-2013SP1-1.0.jar:na]
>           at com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy.processItem(PageDeploy.java:118)
>   ~[cd_deployer-2013.sp1.hr1.jar:na]
>           at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:83)
>   ~[cd_deployer-2013.sp1.hr1.jar:na]
>           at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:87)
>   ~[cd_deployer-2013.sp1.hr1.jar:na]
>           at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:87)
>   ~[cd_deployer-2013.sp1.hr1.jar:na]
>           at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:87)
>   ~[cd_deployer-2013.sp1.hr1.jar:na]
>           at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.process(SectionVisitor.java:60)
>   ~[cd_deployer-2013.sp1.hr1.jar:na]
>           at com.tridion.deployer.extensions.deploy.modules.PageDeploy.process(PageDeploy.java:50)
>   ~[sdl_custom_deployer-2013SP1-1.0.jar:na]
>           at com.tridion.deployer.Processor.process(Processor.java:109) ~[cd_deployer-2013.sp1.hr1.jar:na]

Comment: Final attempt in Phase: Deployment Processing Phase failed for transaction: tcm:0-758380-66560 2016-07-21 09:59:21,351 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Original stack trace for transaction: tcm:0-758380-66560 com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: com.tridion.deployer.ProcessingException: Problem with searchIdent fiks_bedrift. Returned ERROR at c

Comment: Welcome to the community. You will get more  answers if the question can be put in more readable and in a clean manner. I have done some basic edits, FYI.

Comment: As Nickoli mentioned, it seems a Database connection issue.Please re-check all DB ports are open and reachable or not (SSL). Is normal publishing happening?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because "The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption."

It looks like your DB connection parameters need looking over. Your database is not accepting connections over SSL, which could be due to the configs on the DB itself or it could be due to network security such as blocked ports or connections. I would first check the DB connection params: port, SSL certificate (or whether your DB is configured for SSL).

Comment: issue is when iam publishing dynamic components depedent pages(nearly 60-70) indexed after that at the deployment stage failed.please find below exception

Comment: 2016-07-27 13:21:33,869 DEBUG MSSQLIndexer - Inserting row into documents.
2016-07-27 13:21:33,869 DEBUG MSSQLIndexer - Inserting row into documents.
2016-07-27 13:21:33,910 ERROR MSSQLIndexer - Queue: Unable to add row.
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Error retrieving database metadata;

Comment: nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server returned an incomplete response. The connection has been closed. ClientConnectionId:2d552cea-bd2d-4fe4-a322-0ebfb5fbcf94".

Comment: as i understanding in database properties file mentained max rows100

Comment: iam guessing increase max rows it may be work fine could please suggest to me

Comment: i checked in data base confgurations i didn't find any ssl certifications

Comment: Can you try publishing a DCP without any dependencies on any pages, does it go though successfully? If it does, then maybe it has something to do with the size of the transaction. It could also be that your connection pool ran out of connections since you mention 60-70 pages get dragged along.